# Error can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python

```
N3 = int(input("Primer valor:"))
N4 = int(input("Segundo valor:"))

N1 = int(str(N3))
N2 = int(str(N4))

print("Su respuesta es", (str(N1)* str(N2)))
```

Comment: You're multiplying a string by a string. I'm not sure what your end goal is, but you are converting a string to an int, then converting it to a string and back to an int, and then back to a string. Remove N1 and N2 and just use N3 * N4.

Comment: thanks bro! im new in this of python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to multiply the string representation of the numbers. You have already converted the input to an integer, so this will suffice:

```
N3 = int(input("Primer valor:"))
N4 = int(input("Segundo valor:"))

value = N3 * N4
print("Su respuesta es", value)
```

Comment: No problem. If this helped you, please mark this answer as solved by clicking the check next to the answer.